# Deserlize Set in jackson via Rest

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

First time on here but long time reader...  Been spinning my wheels on this and having a tough time finding a way to complete something using Jackson and Wink to desearlize a set of Objects that are sent over.  For some reason the HashSet in this can't be cast properly.  Here is an example: I have an Object Foo which is an entity in the DAO.  I can serealize and deseralize a singel Foo object, which contains Sets and List and etc, no problem.  Here is my 
Foo object:

```
[{"uuid":"1","version":1,"salutation":null,"firstName":"Random1","lastName":"Dude1"},
{"uuid":"2","version":1,"salutation":null,"firstName":"Random2","lastName":"Dude2"}]
```

What I have been trying to do is this in a Rest service using Wink and Jackson.  Example below:

```
@Resource
BarManager barManager

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Bar addFoosForBar(@PathParam("id") String id, Set<Foo> foos) {
Bar bar = barManager.getById(id);
bar.addFoos(foos);
return barManager.update(bar);
}
```

This is example code and barManager.getById(id) is a find resource(@Resource annotated) the retrieves Bar objects.  The "addFoos" methods adds a set of Foo to Bar or in this case adding foos to the lookuped bar. In this code foos in the rest service come back and I can inspect the foos and it looks exactly like the json object but I get an exception “java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.model.Foo” when I try to use foos as a set, i.e. try to iterate through etc.
My question is can Jackson deserialize a set of Objects that are Entities or do you have to define a separate Object type that is a set of Entities just specifically as a map for Jackson to use?   To sum it up, how does Jackson take into account HashSets of defined objects for deserialization?  Having trouble lighting a fuse on a direction to take on this one because it should be straight forward that I just want to deserialize the set and be able to manipulate it in the rest service as POJO.

Comment: What do you expect? How your example function should be called? Specify the input format, for example giving example JSON request.

Comment: Added some clarification on this rest service but just looking to update the bar with a set of foos to answer your first question.  This is called via a URL by the at @Path("{id]") in this case a rest service.  The input format is above in the payload sent over from the client.  If I inspect foos inside the JVM it looks exactly like the above JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to be able to deserlize sets of known entities in Jackson.  used ObjectMapper and defined on each rest services as below example:

```
@Resource
BarManager barManager

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Bar addFoosForBar(@PathParam("id") String id, String foos) {

HashSet<foos> foosSet = null;
JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(HashSet.class, Foo.class);
try {
     fooSet = mapper.readValue(foos, javaType);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

Bar bar = barManager.getById(id);
bar.addFoos(foos);
return barManager.update(bar);
}
```

Not the greatest work but will do the trick on making sets, lists, and whatever on a known defined class with a constructor for Jackson.  Hope this helps someone.